# Yechezkel 42:22-23

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, shevatim-12-tribes, ezekiel--the-book

Yechezkel 42:22 and 23 speaks of the stranger that sojourns with the Israelites that eventually converts and is allowed to receive the tribal inheritance. How does this work if they are not members of any tribe?

Comment: At the conclusion of the final redemption, all the tribes together are going to contribute property to the righteous converts. Until that time, they have no possession in the land of Israel. The righteous convert is associated with the whole of the Jewish people, the Tzibbur, and not with any individual tribe. This status is in keeping with the decision by the court of Moshe Rabbeinu mention in the Torah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Find a source and that's an answer right there

Comment: @Ephraim77 Fascinating question. wish i could upvote but I've reached my limit

Comment: @YaacovDeane Does this also apply to yesomim, or those who have no halachic father?

Comment: @SAH All those people who are Jews by birth are going to be reunited with their actual parents whether they know who they are or not (meaning orphans). That's another one of the benefits of resurrection, which happens during the days of Moshiach. I don't know what you mean by "halachic father". If your intent is one whose father isn't Jewish, that is the same case that Moshe Rabbeinu decided (See VaYikra 24:10-11). They have no inheritance, similar to a convert.